# Add auto prefix by mapping the fields names

Tags: java, datamapper, orika, data-mapping

I use [Orika Mapper](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html) and have the following:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(BusinessResource.class, BusinessDto.class)
                .field("content._id", "_id")
                .field("content.uuid", "uuid")
                .field("content.created", "created")
                .field("content.name", "name")
                .field("content.phone", "phone")
                .field("content.fax", "fax")
                .field("content.email", "email")
                .field("content.address", "address")
                .field("content.coordinates", "coordinates")...
```

Why I have to use it this way? Because of BusinessResoruce:

```
public class BusinessResource extends Resource<Business> {
   private Business content;
   private Link[] links;
}
```

Is it possible to make some auto prefix by mapping which will add `content.`to every `field`method?

Thank you in advance

UPDATE #1: Tried to use `DefaultFieldMapper` and removed all the manual mappings - without success, but Links object is mapped by default without any problem. The main problem with this solution:

```
suggestMappedField(String fromProperty, Type<?> fromPropertyType)
```

receives the properties of `BusinessResource` which are `content` and `links`, and that's why the resulted object if empty..

Answer (score 1):

Orika provide a way to give it a hint about how to do auto mapping : [DefaultFieldMapper](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/DefaultFieldMapper.java)

You can use it on class map levels or even  registering the default field mapper globally.

Here is an example:

```
DefaultFieldMapper myHint = new DefaultFieldMapper() {
public String suggestMappedField(String fromProperty, Type<?> fromPropertyType) {
  return "content." + fromProperty;
}};
```

You can create default

```
factory.registerDefaultFieldMapper(myHint);
// OR factory.classMap() ... .byDefault(myHint);
```

Comment: Can't make your solution work.. All the fields are empty, but as soon as I add the `field("content.id", "id")`- works fine..

Comment: Can you please inverse mapping: 
mapperFactory.classMap( BusinessDto.class, BusinessResource.class).byDefault(myHint).register()

Comment: You have to make sure that the suggestMappedField receive _id, uuid and so on  (may you need just to flip the order of BusinessDto and BusinessResource)

Comment: As I said I tried in both directions... the same result in both cases. Please take a look at my test project - https://github.com/vicmosin/orika-test - I have to understand if it's orika's issue or mine. Thanks!